# Using Dataset returned when using ExecuteDataSet

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am using Enterprise block and not able to figure this out.

I am using oracle procedure for inserting records into the database from my asp.net application in VB.net

Though it is inserting records as it should When I try to access the dataset returned I am not able to see the just inserted record details.

In my Oracle procedure I have Output Cursor which should return several column values from the just inserted record.

Please help.

Comment: ublic Function InsertData(ByVal query As String, ByVal param() As Object) As DataSet
            Try
 
                'stored Proc
then return the dataset
                dataSet = db.ExecuteDataSet(query, param)
 
            Catch ex As SqlClient.SqlException
                Throw
            Catch ex As DbException
                Throw
            End Try
            Return dataSet
        End Function

How do I access the returned dataset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit of a work around to what you're currently doing, but if you're still having issues with this, I'd suggest running `ExecuteNonQuery` for inserting and then `ExecuteDataTable` with the data you supplied to call a `SELECT` on your data.

Keep in mind, however, that this method's performance may be a bit slower (DB call to insert, followed by a DB call and return to select the data), but you will not need to worry about your cursor anymore (not sure what kind of performance gain, if any, this might have).